# Can I increase the frame rate of an animation while keeping it the same length?

Tags: animation

I made an animation in 24 fps and when I render it, I see quite a few bits that are choppy, rendering in 30fps would improve this. The problem is that makes my movie shorter. To keep it the same length I would have to obviously increase the number of frames, but I would then have to shift all my keyframing by different amounts. Is there any way to automatically adjust this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Beneath the Frame Rate dropdown in the render panel, there is a time remapping section. Set the old mapping to 24 and the new to 30. For more in-depth info, see here: http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/media/blender-tips-and-tricks.php

Comment: That only seems to affect the placement of the active green line on the timeline and not my keyframes.

Comment: Not only that, no. If you then render again with 30fps, blender will use subframes for rendering, so you get the additional frames you are looking for. No need to scale all keyframes then.

Comment: But using subframes only simulates 30fps it doesn't make it 30fps. Only by re-rendering the entire scene with correct shifting of keyframes will I get true 30fps, correct?

Comment: Nope, internally it won't render the original frames, but use fractions of them. So instead of rendering (the original) frames 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 it will actually use 1.6, 2.4, 3.2, 4, 4.8

Answer (score 3):

I found a relatively easy way by going into the dope sheet, selecting all, scaling by 1.25 (to go from 24fps to 30fps). Then grab all points and slide so the first keyframe is at frame 1 again. Then set the end frame also to 1.25x the original frame length.

Comment: A tip there - the dopesheet scales from the current frame (shown with a green line) - go to frame 1 then scale. In the graph editor you can choose 2d cursor as the pivot point (in the header) and scale on x from frame 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can render at 30 fps, then bring it into the compositor and render it out as a movie at 24fps. You also could in the graph editor scale all of your key-frames in the x-axis, you would have to extend the render end frame.