# Offset in selecting frames on the timeline

Tags: dopesheet, timeline

My Dopesheet shows different frame to the one in timeline making such the whole project unsynced.

I noticed that when passing the frames in Dopesheet when I select frame 24 it jumps to frame 26, while timeline shows frame 25. At frame 50 it does the same thing.

It goes accumulating, so when I get to frame 500, the difference is like 12 frames. Anyone experienced the same thing? I don't know how to get back to sync it again.

[image: timeline and dope sheet out of sync]

Comment: WOW,Solved,thanks a lot Mr Zak,i had no idea about this option in render tab.Yes,i had the new one set to 98,had to change it by accident...that's 2 days of headache solved in 2 minutes :-) thanks again for quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When number of frame which is selected in the Timeline / any of animation editors isn't the same as in the *Current Frame* value this means they are remapped to other values of Frames Per Second.
The unusual behaviour can be noticed even when clicking on frames in animation editors.

[image: framerate not the same]

If this is not desired then change it back to default values for both *Old mapping value* and *New mapping value* (see [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/output.html) about these options):

[image: frame rate options]
These values are 100 by default, but you can change it to any ones if they are the same.

---

[Can I increase the frame rate of an animation while keeping it the same length?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/can-i-increase-the-frame-rate-of-an-animation-while-keeping-it-the-same-length).

[How can I modify the frame rate without changing overall animation speed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed).