# How do I make a 30fps animation 60?

Tags: animation

How do I make a animation that is 30fps to 60. I think I just x2 slow down the whole animation then I can render it and it will look like it would without breaking anything. Or is there a different method?

Comment: If you don't have simulations or per-frame imports (image sequences, mesh sequences) it is ok

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I increase the frame rate of an animation while keeping it the same length?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/can-i-increase-the-frame-rate-of-an-animation-while-keeping-it-the-same-length)

Comment: I know it's off-topic, but this is just a comment. There are a few free, ai operated framerate upscaling software on the internet for example DAIN or RIFE. They worth a try,.

Answer (score 0):

method 1: Time Remapping

[image]

method 2: scripting
move keypoints for all objects via python:

```
import bpy

def scale_kf(oj, fac):
    try:
        for fc in oj.animation_data.action.fcurves:
            for kp in fc.keyframe_points:
                kp.co[0] *= fac
    except: pass

for oj in bpy.data.objects:
    scale_kf(oj, 2)
```